# Config based Hide Show Rules Processor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a library which does DOM hide and show based on other DOM elements.

I have written a basic structure for the library.

The below is the code to handle DOM elements hiding when a checkbox is checked and unchecked.

My overall goal is to make this library extensible and maintainable.

Am I following SOLID principles? Is there any better way to do it? Are there any design patterns to follow?

```
// basic data structure of config object
var rules = [
  {
    sourceId: 'mainCheckbox',
    targetId: 'exampleDiv1',
    ruleType: 'onlyOnChecked',
    targetVisibilityOnChecked: 'hide', // show / hide
    targetVisibilityOnUnchecked: 'show',
    doNotReset: false
  }
]

var ruleToProcessorMap = {
  onlyOnChecked: OnlyOnCheckedRuleProcessor
}

var RuleEngine = {}

RuleEngine.run = function(rules) {
  var ruleIndex
  for (ruleIndex = 0; ruleIndex < rules.length; rules++) {
    this.processRule(rules[ruleIndex])
  }
}

RuleEngine.processRule = function(ruleObj) {
  var ruleProcessor = new ruleToProcessorMap[ruleObj.ruleType](ruleObj)
  ruleProcessor.process()
}

function OnlyOnCheckedRuleProcessor(options) {
  this.options = options || {}
}

OnlyOnCheckedRuleProcessor.prototype.process = function() {
  var $sourceId = $id(this.options.sourceId),
    ctx = this

  $sourceId.on('click', onSourceClick)

  function onSourceClick() {
    var elementVisibilityHandler = new ElementVisibilityHandler({
        elementId: ctx.options.targetId,
        doNotReset: ctx.options.doNotReset
      }),
      show = elementVisibilityHandler.show,
      hide = elementVisibilityHandler.hide

    var visibilityMap = {
      show: show,
      hide: hide
    }

    var onCheckedFunc = visibilityMap[ctx.options.targetVisibilityOnChecked]
    var onUncheckedFunc = visibilityMap[ctx.options.targetVisibilityOnUnchecked]

    if ($sourceId.is(':checked')) {
      onCheckedFunc.call(elementVisibilityHandler)
    } else {
      onUncheckedFunc.call(elementVisibilityHandler)
    }
  }
}

function ElementVisibilityHandler(options) {
  this.options = options || {}

  this.$element = $id(options.elementId)
}

ElementVisibilityHandler.prototype.show = function() {
  if (isContainerElement(this.$element)) {
    if (this.options.doNotReset) {
      simpleShow(this.$element)
    } else {
      showWithChildren(this.$element)
    }
  }
}

ElementVisibilityHandler.prototype.hide = function() {
  if (isContainerElement(this.$element)) {
    if (this.options.doNotReset) {
      simpleHide(this.$element)
    } else {
      hideAndResetChildren(this.$element)
    }
  }
}

function simpleHide($element) {
  return $element.hide()
}

function hideAndResetChildren($element) {
  var $children = simpleHide($element)
    .children()
    .hide()

  $children.find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)

  $children.find('textarea, input').val('')
}

function simpleShow($element) {
  return $element.show()
}

function showWithChildren($element) {
  simpleShow($element)
    .children()
    .show()
}

function $id(elementId) {
  return $('#' + elementId)
}

function isContainerElement($element) {
  if (typeof $element === 'string') {
    $element = $id($element)
  }

  return $element.prop('tagName').toLowerCase()
}

// execution starts here
RuleEngine.run(rules)
```

Comment: I think this question should be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/